# Misleading results with Kruskal-Wallis + Posthoc Test

Tags: statistical-significance, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, boxplot

[Dataset](http://pastebin.com/MJFvyCZ0): Rows are cross validation sets and columns are different regression methods. The dataset contains RMS error values on a benchmark regression problem. So, lower is better.

Here is a boxplot of the data. Methods 9, 10, 11 and 12 are visually much better than others.
[image]

I want to identify the methods that are *significantly* better than others. 
I used Kruskal-Wallis test (built-in MATLAB function) and could easily reject $H_0$= All groups are from same distribution. So, I proceed to use MATLAB's `multcompare` with default settings. I find that methods 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11 and 12 are statistically indistinguishable.

Commands used:

> [p,tbl,teststats] = kruskalwallis(Dataset,[],'on')
>
> c = multcompare(teststats,'alpha',0.05)

Why is there such disagreement between the boxplot and the statistical test?

Edit: It would be really great if someone could run the same tests on the data.

Comment: 1. Your raw numbers in your link don't indicate how the data are organized (which numbers go with which method?) -- don't make it our job to guess what your data mean. 2. What are the response values measuring? "error values" is a little unclear.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Can you give some sense of what those default settings are and what they do with Kruskal Wallis?

Comment: For the kruskalwallis function, there are three arguments (i) the dataset with samples in rows and groups in columns, (ii) Group names, (iii) Display table. For multcompare, the default choice of posthoc test is 'tukey-kramer'. Other option are 'dunn-sidak', 'bonferroni' and 'scheffe'. The default alpha value is 0.05.

Comment: Any kind of input will be useful.

Comment: I seem to recall that I got similar results to yours using R (but that was before you responded on the defaults, so it will definitely be with different defaults on the multiple comparisons).

Comment: I have read a lot of posts on multiple comparisons. I don't think I am doing anything wrong. But it would be reassuring if someone confirmed what I get.